# Why PHP continue to output to CSV file after fclose()?

Tags: php, fclose

On a web page, I am writing some data into a CSV file using the below code and finally closing with fclose();

```
header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename);
$out = fopen('php://output', 'w');
fputcsv($out, $cvs_cols);
fclose($out);
echo "HELLO WORLD"; // sneaks into CSV!?
```

Why is it that "HELLO WORLD" gets into the CSV download file when it has already fclose()? I want to output the rest of the HTML for the page to be displayed in the browser. How can I do that?

Comment: "HELLO WORLD" is actually my HTML that I want to send to browser, but like I said, they go into the CVS file.

Comment: You haven't re-routed the output though, and as the document is still being constructed by the executing PHP code, the contents of the echo will be appended to the CSV.

Comment: Care to explain downvote?

Comment: It doesn't continue to output to the CSV, but because you're writing your csv to php://output and echos also go to php://output, then the two are going to the same place

Comment: @Jake Not my downvote! If anything, I think this is a good question! :)

Comment: @MarkBaker but I already fclose(). Do I need to fopen() something else?

Comment: fclose() closes the file handle for file writing functions, such as fwrite(), fputcsv(), etc.... but php://output is __also__ the standard output stream for echo, print, etc.... it's equivalent to having to file handles for the same file, and you're only closing one of them

Comment: The solution is __NOT__ to use any echo, print or var_dump type statements in code where you also open/write to php://output

Comment: You cannot send both an HTML response __and__ a CSV (or indeed any other filetype) response in the same request

Comment: @MarkBaker I think I get you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After 1 HTTP request follows 1 response. You cannot send content type `text/csv` and content type `text/html` at the same time (maybe yes with [SPDY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SPDY), but not with pure HTTP).

`fclose` closes your file descriptor but not the output to the browser.

You should also set a `Content-Length` header and put in the filesize.

Mark Baker already gave the most important point in the comments:

`echo` and writing to `php://output` puts content into the same stream: [`STDOUT`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.io-streams.php). Other options would be to write the CSV to memory (but its senseless if you don't use it) or to a file. Read more about the those streams: http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.io-streams.php

**Possible solution:**

You need 2 HTTP requests. 1 For the download, the other for your HTML. Most popular way is it to first use the HTML response and put something in like

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh"
      content="3; URL=http://yourserver.com/download.php?id=pdf&amp;id=123" />
```

This starts the download after 3 seconds.

Comment: Thanks, good links and explanations. Didn't realise there is only one output stream initially, now I can clearly see it.

Answer (score 4):

**There is no 'CSV File' (yet).**

What you are doing is sending a data stream to the client, and telling the client that this stream has a `Content-Type` of `text/csv` and a `filename` of `$filename`.  The client can then chose to save this as a CSV file or just display it in the browser.

This code:

```
$out = fopen('php://output', 'w');
fputcsv($out, $cvs_cols);
fclose($out);
```

Is effectively doing the same thing that `echo $cvs_cols` would do (with a little extra stuff to format a csv output).

So when there is a call to `echo "HELLO WORLD";` it gets sent in the same data steam as the contents of the `$cvs_cols` variable.

When you call `fopen('php://output', 'w')` you are creating a second file handle to `php://output` as one is created by default to output from calls to `echo` etc. So when you are calling `fclose($out)` you're only closing the second file handle.

Answer (score 2):

A very old thread here but to fix this I just added a simple exit(); command. So a button calls the same page with a query string of 'action=export_csv' then that action is run with the exit(); on the last line, hope that helps out.

```
<a href="?action=export_csv">Export CSV</a>
```

Then the 'action' on the page is:

```
if(isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action']=='export_csv'){
    // output headers so that the file is downloaded rather than displayed
    header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=email-responses.csv');

    // create a file pointer connected to the output stream
    $output = fopen('php://output', 'w');

    // output the column headings
    fputcsv($output, array('Email address'));

    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=hostname_mysql;dbname=database_mysql;charset=UTF8', username_mysql, password_mysql);
    $query = "SELECT XXX FROM XXXX";
    $result = $db->query($query);
    $data = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    // loop over the rows, outputting them
    foreach($data as $row){
        fputcsv($output, $row);
    }
    fclose($output);
    exit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use

**ob_clean()** : ob_clean — Clean (erase) the output buffer

**flush()** : flush — Flush the output buffer([flush](https://www.php.net/flush))

```
ob_start();

header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename);
$out = fopen('php://output', 'w');
fputcsv($out, $cvs_cols);
fclose($out);

ob_end_clean();   //    the buffer and never prints or returns anything.


echo "HELLO WORLD"; // sneaks into CSV!?
```